# Please help me repair my update catalog

Tags: command-line, software-update, catalina, repair

I have a MacBook Pro 15" mid 2014 model. I was attempting to fix catalog issues because I could not install Catalina.  Now, all I am offered is Catalina Beta.

I used the command

```
/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --set-catalog https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.15beta-10.15-10.14-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog.gz
```

I'm sorry, i'm just not as familiar with this filesystem as I am with Ubuntu.  I don't want to make things worse.  I am a Windows / Linux IT guy that just happens to have a daughter with a MacBook that needs to be updated.

FYI, I attempted the regular update process using Finder about mac and it just stated that Mojave was the latest update and that I was up to date.

Comment: App Store.app doesn't offer Catalina?

Comment: A proper seed would be https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.15-10.14-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog.gz (excerpt: <date>2019-11-05T18:31:37Z</date>) **and** remove everything after *.gz in your command. There is a large "typo" or c&p error.

Comment: yes, thats a copy / paste typo. I've fixed it above

Comment: Well, it says I'm up to date with Mojave 10.14.6 again instead of offering Catalina Beta. Oh well it works fine i'll leave it alone.  I hear Catalina isn't working so well ;)